# Direct sum of Hilbert Space $\ell^{2}$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, direct-sum

Let $\ell^{2}$ be the Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$. With inner product
\begin{equation}
(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_{k}\bar{y_{k}} 
\end{equation}
Consider the mapping $f:\ell^{2} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{k}}{k},\qquad (x = (x_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{2})
\end{equation}
Now let $\mathcal{N}(f)$ be the nullspace of $f$ and let $\langle v \rangle$ be the span of a vector $v \in \ell^{2}$. Show there exists a vector $y \in \ell^{2}$ such that $\mathcal{N}(f) + \langle y \rangle = \ell^{2}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know of any "easier" versions of this (potentially for a finite dimension inner product space)?

Comment: In general I know that if we have a closed subspace of a Hilbert space we can write the hilbert space as a direct sum of the closed subspace and its orthogonal complement. The nullspace of f is closed (which can easily be shown). After that I was trying to show that the span of y equals the orthogonal complement of the null space of f. However, I didn't manage in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

$f:\ell^{2} \to \mathbb{C}$ is linear and there is $y \in \ell^2$ such that $f(y) \ne 0$, hence $f( \ell^2)= \mathbb C$.

The quotient space $ \ell^2/\mathcal{N}(f)$ is isomorphic to $f( \ell^2)= \mathbb C$.

Therefore $ \dim \ell^2/\mathcal{N}(f)=1$.

This gives

$$\mathcal{N}(f) \oplus \langle y \rangle= \ell^2.$$